# H1 tag value not showing when page loads up in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Problem: when the page first loads up, the PageHeader H1 tag shows a blank value instead of "New Page". Why does this happen and how can I make it show "New Page"?

In Page.js

```
const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState('New Page');
const pageTitleChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setPageTitle(e.target.innerText);
}

return (
     <PageHeader title = {pageTitle} onChange = {pageTitleChangeHandler}></PageHeader>
);
```

In PageHeader.js

```
return (
        <div className = "page-header">
            <h1 
                className = "page-header-text" 
                contentEditable = "true" 
                onInput = {props.onChange} 
                value = {props.title}>
            </h1>
        </div>
);
```

Comment: Try this way --->https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-booth-60c1q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: <h1>{props.title}</h1>

Comment: @SarunUK in the sandbox you have linked, if I provide any input to the H1 tag, it adds it inverted to the string. That's why I am passing value property to the H1 tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove `value` attribute from h1 tag and set `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` instead like

```
import React from "react";
export default function PageHeader(props) {
  return (
    <div className="page-header">
      <h1
        className="page-header-text"
        contentEditable="true"
        onInput={props.onChange}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.title }}
      >
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. But this runs into the same issue with inverted caret input. Try changing the title here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-booth-60c1q?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

If you want `New Page` to show up on page load, you need to change the argument to `setPageTitle` from `e.target.innerText` to `e.target.value`, and add `{props.title}` in the `h1` tag.

Then you can change `onInput` to `onKeyDown`.

This alone would delete `New Page` from the header once you edit. To avoid this, simply change `title={pageTitle}` to `title={"New Page"}`.

```
const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState('New Page');
const pageTitleChangeHandler = (e) => {
    // This will set the value prop
    setPageTitle(e.target.value);
}

  return (
    <PageHeader
      title={"New Page"}
      onChange={pageTitleChangeHandler}
    ></PageHeader>
  );
}

const PageHeader = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="page-header">
      <h1
        className="page-header-text"
        contentEditable="true"
        onKeyDown={props.onChange}
        value={props.title}
      >
        {props.title}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Hey! How to prevent it from deleting "New page" upon input from the user?

Comment: @AdityaKarad I edited the answer to prevent deletion of the original title.